# How do I create a page based on a record in a database?

Tags: asp.net, database, dynamic

Okay, so I have an ASP website that I've tied in with a database. I've used a Datalist element to generate a list of the records on my webpage (which includes photos, text, date/time objects). I want to be able to click on that record and it inserts its data and its related records into a page template. As an example, the website I'm building is a travel blog. The home page will have several different entries on it, each being their own record in a database. When I click on one of the records, I want it to take me to a page where all the photos that will be associated with the entry and its related text will be displayed in a templated page. Does that make sense?

Comment: So what have you tried or are you expecting someone on here to make this for you?

Comment: Lol, no, I don't expect someone to make it for me. I just have no idea even how to do it. Are there multiple ways to do it? It will probably seem like I'm asking someone to make it for me, but I just don't have much of an idea how it is doable.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but there is no scaffolding built into ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC has the concept of scaffolding, which can look at your model and based on the type make controls for your view (i.e. Add-Edit-Delete pages, etc.). I am not sure if you are looking for some type of automation to do this or if you just want to build an .aspx page that can hold your layout and you populate it with each individual record's data.

Comment: I remember downloading MVC, but I started building the website before I downloaded it. So I'd wager I haven't been building the website with MVC in mind. I don't know if my last sentence even made sense. But I can tell you that I want to do the last part of your comment. Here's a couple of links that serve as an example of what I'd like to do.

http://www.phrd.com/attorney-bio.asp?AttorneyID=498

Where "498" is the ID of the attorney in the database. It pulls all his information from the database and puts it in the attorney-bio.asp page.

Comment: Is that using MVC? I'm not sure you can tell just by the example.

Comment: it is built on classic ASP, precursor to ASP.NET from the 1990's.

Comment: You said you have a website tied to a database, what pages currently exist?

Comment: I would recommend posting your code and the data access you have setup, then people can recommend better options for you.

Comment: Well, I'll have to do that later. I appreciate your conversation. It's helped me focus a little more.